# ListView not clickable with android:background set

Tags: android, android-layout, listview

I have a custom `ListView.` Whenever I set the `android:background` attribute to the row layout its not clickable. Also I had set a layout background for the `ListView.` and when I scroll it gives the background it has set and when it stops to scroll it takes up the color of `LinearLayout.` My code is as below for `ListView` and the individual row layout. I tried putting set `android:focusable="false"` in the `xml` for the row layout but the whenever I set the `android:background` its not clickable. Whenever I scroll it gets to white and then turns black. Also when I set the `android:background` attribute in the row layout `TextView` its not clickable. Main layout is as below..

```
       <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:background="#000000"
        android:orientation="vertical" >
        <LinearLayout 
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:background="#000000"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >
    <TextView android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:text="hello"/>
    <TextView android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="hello"/>
    <TextView android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:text="hello"/>
    </LinearLayout>
    <ListView android:id="@+id/list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        ></ListView>
    </LinearLayout>

The row layout xml

    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- Copyright (C) 2007 The Android Open Source Project

     Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
     you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
     You may obtain a copy of the License at

          http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0

     Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
     distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
     WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
     See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
     limitations under the License.
-->

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">


    <TextView 
        android:focusable="false"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
        android:textSize="28sp"
        android:id="@+id/text"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:background="#000000" //Doesn't work with this
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:layout_width="0dip"
        android:layout_weight="1.0"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</LinearLayout>

The MainActivity.java



     package com.example.list;

    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.content.Context;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.view.LayoutInflater;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.ViewGroup;
    import android.widget.AdapterView;
    import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
    import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
    import android.widget.ListView;
    import android.widget.TextView;
    import android.widget.Toast;


    /**
     * Demonstrates how to write an efficient list adapter. The adapter used in this example binds
     * to an ImageView and to a TextView for each row in the list.
     *
     * To work efficiently the adapter implemented here uses two techniques:
     * - It reuses the convertView passed to getView() to avoid inflating View when it is not necessary
     * - It uses the ViewHolder pattern to avoid calling findViewById() when it is not necessary
     *
     * The ViewHolder pattern consists in storing a data structure in the tag of the view returned by
     * getView(). This data structures contains references to the views we want to bind data to, thus
     * avoiding calls to findViewById() every time getView() is invoked.
     */
    public class MainActivity extends Activity {

        private static class EfficientAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
            private LayoutInflater mInflater;

            public EfficientAdapter(Context context) {
                // Cache the LayoutInflate to avoid asking for a new one each time.
                mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);

                // Icons bound to the rows.
            }

            /**
             * The number of items in the list is determined by the number of speeches
             * in our array.
             *
             * @see android.widget.ListAdapter#getCount()
             */
            public int getCount() {
                return DATA.length;
            }

            /**
             * Since the data comes from an array, just returning the index is
             * sufficent to get at the data. If we were using a more complex data
             * structure, we would return whatever object represents one row in the
             * list.
             *
             * @see android.widget.ListAdapter#getItem(int)
             */
            public Object getItem(int position) {
                return position;
            }

            /**
             * Use the array index as a unique id.
             *
             * @see android.widget.ListAdapter#getItemId(int)
             */
            public long getItemId(int position) {
                return position;
            }

            /**
             * Make a view to hold each row.
             *
             * @see android.widget.ListAdapter#getView(int, android.view.View,
             *      android.view.ViewGroup)
             */
            public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
                // A ViewHolder keeps references to children views to avoid unneccessary calls
                // to findViewById() on each row.
                ViewHolder holder;

                // When convertView is not null, we can reuse it directly, there is no need
                // to reinflate it. We only inflate a new View when the convertView supplied
                // by ListView is null.
                if (convertView == null) {
                    convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.rowlayout, null);

                    // Creates a ViewHolder and store references to the two children views
                    // we want to bind data to.
                    holder = new ViewHolder();
                    holder.text = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.text);
                    convertView.setTag(holder);
                } else {
                    // Get the ViewHolder back to get fast access to the TextView
                    // and the ImageView.
                    holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
                }

                // Bind the data efficiently with the holder.
                holder.text.setText(DATA[position]);
                return convertView;
            }

            static class ViewHolder {
                TextView text;
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
            ListView lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
            lv.setFocusable(true);
            lv.setFastScrollEnabled(true);
            lv.setAdapter(new EfficientAdapter(this));
            lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener()
            {
                @Override public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,int position, long arg3)
                { 
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Hello : " + position, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });

        }

        private static final String[] DATA = {
                "Abbaye de Belloc", "Abbaye du Mont des Cats", "Abertam",
                "Abondance", "Ackawi", "Acorn", "Adelost", "Affidelice au Chablis",
                "Afuega'l Pitu", "Airag", "Airedale", "Aisy Cendre",
                "Allgauer Emmentaler", "Alverca", "Ambert", "American Cheese",
                "Ami du Chambertin", "Anejo Enchilado", "Anneau du Vic-Bilh",
                "Anthoriro", "Appenzell", "Aragon", "Ardi Gasna", "Ardrahan",
                "Armenian String", "Aromes au Gene de Marc", "Asadero", "Asiago",
                "Aubisque Pyrenees", "Autun", "Avaxtskyr", "Baby Swiss", "Babybel",
                "Baguette Laonnaise", "Bakers", "Baladi", "Balaton", "Bandal",
                "Banon", "Barry's Bay Cheddar", "Basing", "Basket Cheese",
                "Bath Cheese", "Bavarian Bergkase", "Baylough", "Beaufort",
                "Beauvoorde", "Beenleigh Blue", "Beer Cheese", "Bel Paese",
                "Bergader", "Bergere Bleue", "Berkswell", "Beyaz Peynir",
                "Bierkase", "Bishop Kennedy", "Blarney", "Bleu d'Auvergne"};
    }
```

Comment: do you want the textview to be clickable ? Then set the clickable property to true. To remove the black and white issues, set the cacheColorHint property to transparent that is, @android:color/transparent

Comment: Thanks @DharaShah but the clickable has to be set to false to make it click. Its weird. The cacheColorHint solved the colour trick. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

The problem has been solved . For the color I have set `android:cacheColorHint="android:color/transparent"`. In order to make it clickable I have to make the TextView as `android:clickable="false"` . I don't know why its so weird.

Comment: and yes a text view does take up focus , as a result all the views in the row layout have to be set to clickable false if only the item click of the listview has to be triggered